# How to restart stack trace when rethrowing an exception?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to restart stack trace given a caught exception? Problem is that when I await a future and it fails, stack trace does not tell which await failed.

For example, stack trace tells that `doSomethingMayFail` failed:

```
def doSomethingMayFail() = Future { throw new RuntimeException("test") }
Await.result(doSomethingMayFail(), 1.seconds)
Await.result(doSomethingMayFail(), 1.seconds)
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: test
    at RandomSpec$$anon$7.$anonfun$doSomethingThatFails$1(RandomSpec.scala:79)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:672)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:431)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Comment: You can try use `Await.ready` instead. It will try to extract the result of the `Future` and when it fails, you'll see which one failed. But if you have a bigger problem you should explain it. I fail to see how knowing which one failed helps you. Usually, you are interested in it's success.

Comment: What's the goal of this? Depending on what you're trying to do, we might give a better answer.

Comment: My actual problem is that I have a method that returns a Future, that is used in a test in many places. When that Future fails,I can't figure out which call failed, as stack trace begins with Future body.

Answer (score 1):

One way to is to catch, `fillInStackTrace` and rethrow the exception.

```
try {
  Await.result(doSomethingThatFails(), 1.seconds)
} catch {
  e => throw e.fillInStackTrace()
}
```